# How can I stop sound in Android when home button is pressed

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I have an app and a music in all activity of my app
I would like that, when user press button home, the sound stops like all game that you can download from android market.

How I can do that?

When user press home button a new intent is fired but android framework prevents to catch the main intent so I can't use a broadcast receiver with this action

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

One solution is to stop music onPause and I restart onResume but in this solution the user hear a second pause when switching from one activity to the next, is not good
I search this solution on many forum but unsuccessfully

P.S.

1. the android framework don't allow to catch the home key onKeyDown event
2. the android framework don't allow to catch the intent launched when user press on home button

Answer (score 1):

You can try puting the code in onUserLeaveHint() method, it belongs to Activity and is called when you press the Home button.

Comment: But the music won't be stopped if he is playing the game and an incoming call arrives to the phone?

Comment: In this case, the music stops if the apps is put into background, whatever the case. @user626920 doesn't want to put the code in onResume() and onPause() because of a sound gap between activities, so i think this is exactly what he wants.

Comment: the method onUserLeaveHint() is called when I pass from one activity to the next, and when I press the home button

Comment: the method onUserLeaveHint is called when I pass from one activity to the next, and when I press the home button. So seretur your solution don't work